# Torque on generator due to reactive power

Tags: voltage, power, current, electromagnetism, electric-machine

Since reactive power goes back and forth from load to generator, so when reactive power goes from load to generator this should manifest as torque that's exerted on the rotor right? (like that of a motor, power being absorbed into the generator). Is my reasoning correct?
And could you please share some relevant litreature regarding this?

Comment: The presence of reactive power will result (in most cases that I can think of) a cyclical reduction in torque seen by the rotor i.e. a slackening of the mechanical load per cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Any load that's purely reactive is not absorbing any energy. Energy delivered to the load is returned to the source, corresponding to the condition of *no* rotor torque.

Conversely, as rotor torque increases, energy *is* transferred, consistent with power equaling the product of torque and angular velocity. This implies that increased rotor torque corresponds to a *less* reactive load.

So, from the perspective of conservation of energy alone, an increase in reactive power would correspond to a reduced rotor torque.

Answer (score 0):

So the question is what does a reactive load feel like to a generator,

Well seeing as a reactive load is characterised by power flowing in opposite directions at different parts of the cycle, I would expect a reactive load to feel coggy with increased torque being needed at some parts of the cycle and reduced  (even negative) torque at others.  The classical fix for a machine like this is to add a flywheel.

Answer (score 0):

No. Reactive power manifests in a motor or generator as extra voltage that does not result in a net current. That is because the current “flows forth and back” during one electrical cycle. So it does not produce any torque. And it does not produce any speed either. Instead, it produces a phase shift between electrical and mechanical cycle or vice versa.